# Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AllAccessDisabled;

Tags: amazon-s3

I have implemented `Amazon S3` in my project. But I am getting `Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AllAccessDisabled;` I fined in google but I have not found this issue. Please tell me where I have done wrong. One more thing When I sign up the `Amazon S3` I have chosen basic not Developer or business.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: All access to this object has been disabled (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AllAccessDisabled; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX), S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
11-28 18:30:00.410 30990-10598/com.example.sanjitpatra.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
11-28 18:30:00.410 30990-10598/com.example.sanjitpatra.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
11-28 18:30:00.410 30990-10598/com.example.sanjitpatra.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
11-28 18:30:00.410 30990-10598/com.example.sanjitpatra.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4375)
11-28 18:30:00.410 30990-10598/com.example.sanjitpatra.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1357)
```

Comment: Assuming you have not made a blatant error in your code, such as accessing entirely the wrong bucket, `AllAccessDisabled` usually signifies a problem with billing or an administrative issue with your account, not a technical problem.  Submit a [billing and account support request](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) -- not technical support -- to verify this, first.  Then advise us here if they find no issue.  Note that billing and account support requests do not require a paid support plan.